# React-Bootstrap's NavDropdown: disable toggle onClick?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have added some CSS to React-Bootstrap's NavDropdown component in order to get it to expand on hover. However, the default click-to-expand behavior is then problematic, as you can click one menu to toggle it open, and then hover over another one, causing two to expand at once. I have demonstrated this here: https://codesandbox.io/s/61vjn41mzz

Is there a way to disable the toggle functionality that comes with React-Bootstrap's NavDropdown? I've tried to call `event.PreventDefault()` and `event.stopPropogation()` with no luck, which you can see in the code sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a good article in helping me understand as well as solve this issue: https://medium.com/@ericclemmons/react-event-preventdefault-78c28c950e46

I ended up using the library "react-native-listener" (referenced in the article) like this:

```
import { NavDropdown } from "react-bootstrap";
import NativeListener from 'react-native-listener';
.
.
.

<NativeListener stopClick>
    <NavDropdown title="Services">
    .
    .
    .
    .

    </NavDropdown>
</NativeListener>
```